# I want to add a variable value, but the result number is displayed as string

Tags: javascript

I want to add the result of the temperature and the result of the `x` variable, but it's not possible, because `var cTemp` is a string.

Here's the code:

```
//Temperature from Puebla
var cTemp;
var dTemp;

var outside = $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(data2){
    lat = data2.lat;
    long = data2.lon;
    var api='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat    + '&lon=' + long + '&appid=cd380bb8125ea7190ceb6ca01bc0f681';

    $.getJSON(api, function(data){
        var kelvin = data.main.temp;
        cTemp = (kelvin - 273).toFixed(1);
        $(".pueblatemp").html(cTemp);
    });
});

var a = cTemp;
var b = x;

var total = a + b;

$('.difference').html(total + "C");
```

Comment: parseInt or parseFloat is your friend.

Comment: First, your `$.getJSON` calls are asynchronous, meaning the result will not occur until after the bottom portion has fired, meaning `cTemp` will be `null`.  I am also not seeing where the `x` variable is declared or assigned so that is likely `undefined`

Comment: _“but it[’]s not possible, bec[a]use `var cTemp` is a string”_ — I don’t follow that reasoning.

Comment: how can I add the two results, is there a way to make the variable cTemp a number, the x variable is just a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling toFixed() will return a string. Leaving cTemp as a number until you come to display it will fix this.

```html
$.getJSON(api, function(data){
        var kelvin = data.main.temp;
        cTemp = kelvin - 273;
        $(".pueblatemp").html(cTemp.toFixed(2));
    });
```

```html
$('.difference').html(total.toFixed(2) + "C");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should bring you closer to what you need to do

```
//Temperature from Puebla
    var cTemp;
    var dTemp;

var outside = $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(data2){
    lat = data2.lat;
    long = data2.lon;
    var api='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat    + '&lon=' + long + '&appid=cd380bb8125ea7190ceb6ca01bc0f681';

    $.getJSON(api, function(data){
        var kelvin = data.main.temp;
        cTemp = (Number(kelvin) - Number(273)).toFixed(1);
        $(".pueblatemp").html(cTemp);

        var a = cTemp;
        var b = x;    //what is x???

        var total = Number(a) + Number(b);

        $('.difference').html(total + "C");

    });
});

console.log("This will run before $.getJSON finishes!!!");
```

Comment: it is being displayed but it is not adding up is is displayed as this 20.0-19.7C

Comment: Added number cast

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

```
 var aStringNumber = "1";
 var anotherStringNumber = "2";
 console.log(aStringNumber + anotherStringNumber); //"12"
 console.log(parseInt(aStringNumber) + parseInt(anotherStringNumber)); //3
```